# How do I get rid of dotted line on x axis of Pandas/Matplotlib bar plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas, plot

EDIT: This line was removed in Pandas (https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/9088).

I am plotting a bar plot using the `plot` function of Pandas. It keeps showing up with a strange dotted line right above the x axis.

It is not the ticks or x axis, both of which I've gotten rid of:

```
plt.tick_params(axis="both", which="both", bottom="off", top="off",  
        labelbottom="on", left="off", right="off", labelleft="on")  
ax.spines["bottom"].set_visible(False)
```

But I still have this dotted line on the x axis! What is that line even called if it not ticks or x axis?

[image: example plot]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

pandas adds a dashed horizontal line on the axis of bar plots.  There is a line in `pandas/tools/plotting.py`, in `BarPlot._post_plot_logic` (line 1842 in my version):

```
ax.axhline(0, color='k', linestyle='--')
```

This doesn't seem to be explicitly documented, and there's apparently no way to stop it from doing this.  Worse, the plot doesn't keep any reference to the line, so there's no clear way to safely remove it.  If the barplot is "plain", then this will work:

```
ax.get_lines()[0].set_visible(False)
```

This only works because in the plain barplot, this is the only Line artist in the plot.  If you do anything else that adds other lines to the plot, it could get tricky to determine which one is the axis line you want to remove.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't think that it may be a pandas-specific thing. Nice catch.